# From Azure VM to ovf

Tags: azure, cloud, google-cloud-platform

I have VM with Windows Server 2012R2 on Microsoft Azure.

I want to "convert" this machine to Google Cloud, What is the way to do that?

I need to convert my Azure VM to OVF?
If so, How can I do that?

If no, what is the best way to move from Azure VM to Google Cloud VM?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try https://www.chromotif.com/ not sure if they have this feature ready but I was talking to one of their PMs and he mentioned that is supported. Haven't tested it.

Worst case you can export your VD from Azure. Download it locally and the reupload to GC.

Answer (score 1):

You need to download VHD/VHDX and convert it on local machine and upload it to GCP.

https://www.file-extensions.org/convert-vhd-to-ovf